# Emit on cancel / complete of an inner observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to understand whether an inner observable wasn't completed successfully (everybody unsubscribed) and to emit a value in this case. A kind of `defaultIfEmpty`, but it doesn't work.

1. There is a trigger (interval).
2. There is a complicated logic that can consume a lot of time (timer).
3. When the trigger is triggered again and is causing cancelation of the complicated logic (switchMap) I want to be notified about it in the stream (to emit a value).

A stackblitz.com example is here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pf8z5z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

the code

```js
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as rxjs from 'rxjs';
import * as operators from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    name = 'Angular';

    protected destroy$ = new rxjs.Subject();

    ngOnInit(): void {
        rxjs.interval(1000).pipe(
            operators.map(() => `${Math.random()}`),
            operators.switchMap(taskId => rxjs.timer(Math.random() * 1000 + 500).pipe(
                operators.mapTo([taskId, 'executed']),

                // something complicated that can be canceled
                // TASK: somehow in case of the cancellation I want to notify the stream

                // start indicator, works fine
                operators.startWith([taskId, 'start']),

                // end indicator, TODO, make it work if the pipe was cancelled
                // when the pipe has been completed - it works.
                operators.endWith([taskId, 'end']),
                operators.catchError(() => rxjs.of([taskId, 'end'])),

                // this works correctly, but it doesn't emit a value.
                operators.finalize(() => console.log(taskId, 'end')),
            )),

            // below is the code that doesn't belong to the task.
            // it displays the issue in the console.

            // checking active tasks
            operators.scan((activeTasks, [taskId, action]) => {
                if (action === 'start') {
                    activeTasks.push(taskId);
                }
                if (action === 'end') {
                    activeTasks.splice(activeTasks.indexOf(taskId), 1);
                }
                if (action === 'cancelled') {
                    activeTasks.splice(activeTasks.indexOf(taskId), 1);
                }
                return [...activeTasks];
            }, []),

            // It should always display just one active task
            // because all others were completed / canceled.
            operators.tap(console.log),
            operators.takeUntil(this.destroy$),
        ).subscribe();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroy$.next();
        this.destroy$.complete();
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**

Possible solution with old school functions.

```js
operators.switchMap(function(taskId, idx) {
    const self = this;
    return rxjs.timer(Math.random() * 1000 + 500).pipe(
        operators.mapTo([taskId, 'executed']),
        operators.startWith([taskId, 'start']),

        // SOLUTION: this works correctly, but has ugly access to switchMap source.
        operators.finalize(() => {
            self.destination.next([taskId, 'end']);
        }),
    );
}),
```

Comment: Did you consider using something like: `merge(src$, interruptSubject)` and `switchMap.pipe(() => timer().pipe(..., finalize(() => interruptSubject.next(...))))` ?

Comment: yes, that's where my thoughts moving to, an own operator that encapsulates this inside. I wouldn't say `concat` bothers me too much, and if code requires more than 1 line to use `switch`, I'm fine to stay with `concat`. I'll play next days more with it. Maybe something would popup. Thank you again! Your implementation helped a lot.

Comment: Glad it helped! Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```js
rxjs.interval(1000).pipe(
  operators.tap(() => console.log('start')),
  operators.switchMap((_, idx) => rxjs.timer(1500).pipe(
    idx > 0 ? operators.startWith('completed') : rxjs.identity,
  )),
  operators.tap(() => console.log('end')),
  operators.takeUntil(this.destroy$),
).subscribe(console.log, console.log);
```

In `switchMap`'s provided function you have [access to the `index`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/switchMap.ts#L122) as well.

If `idx === 0`, it means there is no active inner observable, so, nothing to unsubscribe from.

Otherwise, assuming that the **current inner observable did not complete** in the meanwhile, if a new outer value comes in, it means that active inner obs will be unsubscribed, that's what `startWith` indicates.

#### Why did `endWith` not work

```js
operators.switchMap(() => rxjs.timer(1500).pipe(
  operators.finalize(() => console.log('this works')),
  operators.endWith('cancelled'),
)),
```

First of all, it's important to mention that

```js
src$.pipe(endWith(value))
```

is the same as

```js
concat(src$, of(value))
```

Which essentially is the same as:

```js
of(src$, of(value))
 .pipe(
  mergeMap(obs$ => obs$, 1) // concurrency set to 1
)
```

As you know, `mergeMap` handles inner observables. An inner observable requires an **inner subscriber**. In this case, each inner subscriber will be added to the `_subscriptions` list of the destination subscriber. In this case, the destination subscriber is the inner subscriber of `switchMap`. Put differently, all the inner subscribers of `mergeMap` can be thought of as children of the `switchMap`'s inner susbcriber.

When a new outer value is intercepted by `switchMap` it will unsubscribe the current inner subscriber. When this happens, it will unsubscribe from all its descendant subscribers, which will do the same for their own descendants and so forth. So, `endWith` won't work because its consumer(`switchMap`'s inner subscriber) unsubscribes.

#### EDIT - the case when the inner observable completes

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    rxjs.interval(1000).pipe(
      operators.tap(() => console.log('start')),
      operators.switchMap(function (_, idx) { 
        return rxjs.timer(Math.random() * 1500).pipe(
        operators.tap(null, null, () => console.warn("complete!")),
        idx > 0 && this.innerSubscription ? operators.startWith(true) : rxjs.identity,
      )}),
      operators.tap(() => console.log('end')),
      operators.takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    ).subscribe(console.log, console.log);
  }
```

`SwitchMapSubscriber.innerSubscription` is `null` when there are no active subscribers(e.g the inner observable completed).

#### Edit 2 - using a subject

This alternative involves using a `Subject`, which will emit every time the inner obs maintained by `switchMap` is unsubscribed.

```js
const interruptSubject = new Subject();

src$ = src$.pipe(
  switchMap(
    (/* ... */) => timer(/* ... */)
      .pipe(
        /* ... */
        finalize(() => interruptSubject.next(/* ...your action here... */))
      )
  )
);

merge(src$, interruptSubject)
  .subscribe(/* ... */)
```

Comment: thanks, but I think `operators.startWith` is an indicator that the pipe has been started, not that it has been canceled / completed, because in case if you put `timer(Math.random() * 1500)` you should see that if the stream was able to do everything in 1000 we still get a `completed` on next emit, when it has been completed already. I'll check your answer deeper later and give you an update.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my answer as well. It uses the internal API though. What do you think?

Comment: I agree, looks like there is not a normal way to do it and the best way is to emit cancel flag when a switch is happening and later in the code handle the case if cancel was emitted for a completed task. It would work I think.

Comment: I think another idea came to mind. Maybe if you'd have: `switchMap(() => timer(...).pipe(idx > 0 startWith(true) : identity, endWith(false)))` and then use a custom cb of `distinctUntilChanged` to decide whether to pass along the value or not. if `(true, true)` then the inner obs didn't get the chance to complete, but if `(false, true)` or `(true, false)` then the inner completed(`(previous, current)`).

Comment: Good one! if it were true and false, in my case it's complicated objects, but the idea with a normal function and access to `this` instead of an arrow function makes sense.

Comment: Hmm. I think there is a way to stick to `true` and `false`, even if you're dealing with objects. You could add another property on the objects you're sending, like: `obj._hasCompleted = trueUnique | falseUnique`, where `trueUnique = Symbol('true') etc...` and make the comparison based on these unique properties.

Comment: In my case it emits a start action for ngrx, then emits some actions for reducers, then it emits an end action  to mark the task as completed. I use concat to guarantee that the end will be emitted. the solution with `function` and `this` works, I've added it to the question. The question - is there a better one?

Comment: could you update your answer with `interruptSubject`? Then I'll mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need the `catchError` operator:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    rxjs.interval(1000).pipe(
      operators.tap(() => console.log('start')),
      operators.switchMap(() => rxjs.timer(1500).pipe(
        operators.finalize(() => console.log('this works')),

        // in case the timer observable above fails, it'll emit 'cancelled'
        operators.catchError((e) => rxjs.of('cancelled')),
      )),
      operators.takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    ).subscribe(console.log);
  }
```

Comment: How do you know it didn't work? You didn't cause any error so check it...

Comment: the code is above in the question, you can play on stackbiz, it doesn't throw errors, and wasn't tend to. The question is not about an error, the question is about cancel / complete of an inner observable.

Comment: Oh, my bad. So you have an inner observable and want to force it to complete under certain conditions. Is that right? In that case, when do you want it to complete? After some time, after a number of emissions...

Comment: The goal is to understand whether it was canceled or not. for example I have a http request in the switchMap if a user clicks a login button too often, then requests are canceled and I want to understand which requests were canceled and which were successful. `succeeded` is clear but the `canceled` is the question.

Comment: Hummmmm that's tricky. We need to understand how switchMap works internally, what does it do when it cancels the ongoing subscription. I'm away from a computer right now, but I'll try something later.

Comment: I think it simply unsubscribes: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/switchMap.ts#L133

I'm fine to invent an own operator, just wanted to be sure I don't miss anything of currently possible solution.

Comment: That's what I was thinking of: a custom operator.

Comment: Take a look at this hacking: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hacking-switchmap

Comment: Nop... false alarm. There are huge flaws in my last approach.

Comment: I've updated the code example. with time `scan` operator has death ids.

Comment: Take a look at this approach: [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma614231636433166?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Apparently it's working for the 2 use cases I've tested it, but I'm not sure if it's useful.

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look tomorrow, quite busy tonight.

Comment: you brought some interesting ideas with your solution. I found a way how to emit on finalise, but requires old school functions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right the problem, you want to emit a message when the trigger emits, and this message has to represent the fact that the previous execution has been cancelled and a new one starts.

If this is the case, then you have to look into the function passed to `switchMap`. In particular such function has to return an Observable that emits the message about cancellation immediately and emits the result of the long complex processing as soon as the processing completes. Such an Observable would look like this

`merge(of([prevTaskId, "cancelled"]), doComplexStuff(taskId))`

where `doComplexStuff` is a function encompassing your code like this

```
function doComplexStuff(taskId: string) {
  prevTaskId = taskId;
  return timer(1500).pipe(
    mapTo([taskId, "executed"]),

    // something complicated that can be canceled
    // TASK: somehow in case of the cancellation I want to notify the stream

    // start indicator, works fine
    startWith([taskId, "start"]),

    // end indicator, TODO, make it work if the pipe was cancelled
    // when the pipe has been completed - it works.
    endWith([taskId, "end"]),
    catchError(() => of([taskId, "end"]))

    // this works correctly, but it doesn't emit a value.
    //operators.finalize(() => console.log(taskId, 'end')),
  );
}
```

So the solution could look like

```
let prevTaskId;
interval(1000)
  .pipe(
    take(10),
    map(() => `${Math.random()}`),
    switchMap((taskId) =>
      merge(of([prevTaskId, "cancelled"]), doComplexStuff(taskId))
    ),

    // below is the code that doesn't belong to the task.
    // it displays the issue in the console.

    // checking active tasks
    scan((activeTasks, [taskId, action]) => {
      if (action === "start") {
        console.log("start", taskId);
        activeTasks.push(taskId);
      }
      if (action === "end") {
        console.log("end", taskId);
        activeTasks.splice(activeTasks.indexOf(taskId), 1);
      }
      if (action === "cancelled") {
        console.log("cancelled", taskId);
        activeTasks.splice(activeTasks.indexOf(taskId), 1);
      }
      return [...activeTasks];
    }, []),

    // It should always display just one active task
    // because all others were completed / canceled.
    tap(console.log)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Here a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-syalwv) for this code